I have an issue setting up the Firebird 5 ODBC driver connection in Windows
I currently have multiple Firebird databasis on my Windows PC running on Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3. We are moving over to Firebird 5 and I'm struggling to get the Firebird ODBC 3 driver set up.
I have installed Firebird 5 and are able to connect to the database while using FlameRobin both using the direct database path as well as the allias. I have also finished setting up the connection and made sure to use the correct alias as well as port number, but when I test the ODBC connection the screen just closes and nothing happens.
We use the 32bit data source.
I have replicated the setups on two PC's and I'm getting the same result.
ODBC driver being used = Firebird_ODBC_3.0.0.11_x64.exe
Any ideas are welcome

If you use 32 bits data source then you need 32 bits ODBC driver and 32 bits Firebird client for it.

Thank you for responding. We are running the system on a 64-bit Windows machine and using the 32-dit ODBC driver.

"ODBC driver being used = Firebird_ODBC_3.0.0.11_x64.exe" and "using the 32-dit ODBC driver" are very contradictory.

Also, you need a Firebird 3 or higher fbclient.dll, as the Firebird ODBC Driver version 3 does not work with the Firebird 2.5 or older client (to be clear, it will connect to older versions, but you need a recent fbclient).

@user13964273 The 64-bit installer installs both the 32-bit and 64-bit variants of the Firebird ODBC driver.

Thanks for your comments. Yes, the 64-bit installer does install both sets of drivers. I have also updated the FBClient.DLL and the GDS32.DLL, but still no joy.

Could you show a screenshot of your ODBC DSN in the ODBC Data Sources (32-bit) application?

"The screen just closes" may imply that the driver throw some exception that cause application to abort. In this case a record about this event must appear in Windows Event Log. Also it is good to install JIT debugger such as WinDBG to catch exceptions ASAP and get an useful stack trace for bug reporting.
